# ViewPager2 canceling child Fragments ViewModels viewModelScope when the page gets off of the offscreenPageLimit

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-viewpager2, coroutinescope

I've just realized now that when I have a `ViewPager2` with many pages at the point where `offscreenPageLimit` can be reached when changing pages, the `ViewModels` of those fragments are cleared, which makes the `viewModelScope` of those `Fragment's` `ViewModels` to be canceled.

Is this a bug from the `ViewPager2`? If not, is there any way to avoid it without having to increase the value of `offscreenPageLimit` and without having to use a `SharedViewModel`?

Comment: maybe a workaround could be use the lifecycleObserver interface in the viewmodel, then initialize a custom scope in the onCreateView lifecycle scope and in the onCleared use yourScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren().  Avoid the yourScope.cancel()

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too.  Drove me crazy with some retrofit calls I was running under viewmodelscope.  Just gave up and used CoroutneScope.  Feel like this is some sort of bug.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32134078)